# Gluon Mobile App crash on Android when trying to sort a Filtered List

Tags: sorting, mobile, sortedlist, gluon

I wan to sort an ObservableList. The code run well on desktop but crash on Android. I'm using Gluon Mobile plugin on NetBeans. I have tried many alternatives but and I can't get it.

Alternative 1:

```
ObservableList<Producto> sortdata = mainFilteredList().stream()
 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Producto::getCampo04))
 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
```

Alternative 2:

```
SortedList<Producto> sortedListx = mainFilteredList.sorted((prod1, prod2) -> prod1.getCampo04().compareToIgnoreCase(prod2.getCampo04()));
```

Alternative 3:

```
FilteredList<Producto> sortedList = new FilteredList<>(mainFilteredList().sorted((prod1, prod2) -> 
                prod1.getCampo04().compareToIgnoreCase(prod2.getCampo04())));
```

---

Where: Producto-> is a model, getCampo04-> a property into the model, mainFilteredList() -> a filtered list of Producto with items.

Any help will be useful.

Comment: Any crash info available?

Comment: Gluon Mobile doen'st support `Streams` yet. If you want to use Streams you will need the  https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/ library

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I have not any log for the crash. I only get a blank view.

Comment: Besides the  `Streams`, `default Methods` could also be a problem. I am not sure if `default methods` are enabled on default in the latest `Gluon Mobile Release` or if you have to enable it via `retrolambda {
    defaultMethods true
}`.